# Loop through children of object until anchor is found with attribute X

Tags: javascript

Say I have a DOM element.

How would I do it in **Javascript**, to find out if that element has any children (or children of children) which is an `<a>` element which href attribute is `'/'`? And if so, return at which level (deep) is it?

So far I have this:

```
var children = element.children
var level = 1;
    for (var i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (children[i].nodeName == 'A' && children[i].href == '/') {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

How can I go to the children of the children?

Comment: loop through `element.getElementsByTagName('a')` looking for `href == '/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
function getLevelOfAnchorWithAttrX (element, attr) {
    var anchor = element.querySelector('a[href="' + attr + '"]');
    if (anchor) {
        var level = 1;
        var levelElement = anchor
        while (levelElement.parentElement !== element) {
            level++;
            levelElement = levelElement.parentElement;
        }
        return level;
    }
}
```

Lookey [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4f3Xd/2/).

Answer (score 0):

With a recursive function:

```
function traverseChildren(el, depth) {
  depth = depth || -1;
  for (var i=0; i < el.children.length; i++) {
    if (children[i].nodeName == 'A' && children[i].href == '/') {
      return ++depth;
    }
    else if (el.children.length > 0) {
      depth = traverseChildren(el, ++depth);
    }
  }
  return depth;
}

var depth = traverseChildren(element, depth);
if (depth != -1) {
  console.log('a element found at ' + depth + ' levels deep');
}
else {
  console.log('no a element found');
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Do you know if by using element.getElementsByTagName('a') would I be able to get the "deep distance"? Also, aren't you missing the recursion here? I mean, you are not going into the children of the children, right when calling depth = traverseChildren(el, ++depth);

Comment: Also, what value would you pass the first time you call traverseChildren(element, 0) ? If so, depth = depth || -1; this is not even needed right?

Comment: The depth argument is there to keep track of the number of levels deep the recursive function has traversed. Calling it without this argument defaults it to -1, which I selected based on convention derived from the result indexOf when no match is found. The default -1 will be the returned value when the an a element is not found at all.

Comment: Alternatively you could find an a element with getElementsByTagName('a') as you suggest and then traverse up its parent chain until parent === window, counting the iterations on the way.